# How to chain multiple subscriptions to an observable, within the observable, in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to prevent duplicate http calls. I have multiple subscriptions on an observable, and that observable has a switchMap which decides if there will be an http call:

```
getModules(): Observable<Module[]> {
  return this.modules$.pipe(
    switchMap((modules: Module[]) => {
      if (!modules) {
        return this.setModules(); // http call, returning observable
      }
      return this.modules$; // observable
    })
  );
}
```

Then there are multiple subscriptions, within different components of the app, calling this method. How can I prevent multiple http calls? I need to delay calling the http observable, not delay the emitted value.

Comment: Would setting a boolean value in the component after the first call then checking that before doing any http stuff work?

Comment: You want to delay it until when? There are btw `shareReplay()` and `share()` so maybe one of them could help you.

Comment: @martin I do not want to delay the emitting of values. I want to prevent the http call if it's currently in progress. I am trying something like Lazy Coder suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this issue thanks to @Lazy Coder:
I added a "busy" flag for getModules(), and left the subscription open for subscribers to be notified for when the http observable updates the source modules$.

```
private getModules(): Observable<Module[]> {
    return this.modules$.pipe(
      switchMap((modules: Module[]) => {
        if (!modules && !this.isBusy) {
          return this.setModules(); // updates the modules$ source when complete
        }
        return this.modules$;
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the `Observable` as a `public` service property instead of calling `getModules().subscribe(...)` everywhere in your code, because you instantiate multiple `Observable` by doing that.
Indeed, the `pipe` operator produces a new `Observable` on every call.

Comment: I tried storing the output of getModules() in the constructor, but the http observable still got called multiple times.

Comment: and you called `getModules()` only once?